# Mysql generate query to generate custom result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a query in rails I can do things in creating an array and putting json object into array:
For example:

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    Districts: "Patna",
    WinterRain_2016: 3.4,
    HotWeatherRain_2016: 56.7,
    SouthWestMonsoonRain_2016: 801.3,
    NorthWestMonsoonRain_2016: 57.8,

},
{
    id: 2,
    Districts: "Nalanda",
    WinterRain_2016: 13.4,
    HotWeatherRain_2016: 48.9,
    SouthWestMonsoonRain_2016: 953.3,
    NorthWestMonsoonRain_2016: 72.1,

}
]
```

This is what I am getting when I running a query all I am getting all values and I am running this some array and I am generating this:

```
 [
    {
    y: 3.4,
    label: "Patna"
    },
    {
    y: 13.4,
    label: "Nalanda"
    }, 
]
```

So my question is can I run a query in rails or mysql and generate result like this.  Here I am creating an array and pushing this hash into it and here I am getting this result. Is it possible to generate this kind of result using query or mysql query if yes then how

Answer (score 0):

you can do this directly in query, instead of creating array first then creating json response.

let take a example of user model query:-

```
User.select(:id, :email).limit(2).map{ |r| {id: r.id, email: r.id} }
```

response

```
 [{:id=>2402, :email=>2402}, {:id=>2399, :email=>2399}]
```

Comment: It is just mapping an array my question is can I do this using plain sql query.